# UVD not responding; ATI/Intel Hybrid after upgrade to 13.04 and turning off ATI

Tags: drivers, ati, hybrid-graphics, vgaswitcheroo, white-screen

First of all I am totally new to Ubuntu and Linux so I am still trying to learn commands and basics.

My laptop is an Acer 4820TG with a hybrid Intel onboard and a ATI radeon mobility HD5650.

Several months ago I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS as a dual boot next to my Windows 7. A few days ago the ATI card decided to die (artifacts and bluescreen while booting). As this is quite an old laptop now (4 years), I wanted to use this opportunity to get back to Ubuntu, as gaming will be not possible any longer anyways. 
So after a lot of googling and searching I managed to boot into Ubuntu 12.04 avoiding my now dead ATI (not as easy as it may sound, for a total beginner that is).
Using the following commands from [Ubuntu Precise Installation](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide)

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
sudo rm -rf /etc/ati
```

followed by switching to the Intel GPU after booting using the following [edits](http://usernamepending.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/getting-back-some-battery-life-in-ubuntu-11-10-by-disabling-discrete-graphics/)

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

changing `"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"`

```
sudo update-grub
gksu gedit /etc/rc.local
```

adding `"sudo echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch"`

This worked quite fine, the ATI card was disabled, temperature went down to 45°C.

Now my goal is to upgrade to 14.04 LTS. However it seemed that using the upgrade option I only had the possibility to upgrade to the next higher version. Therefore I first upgraded to 12.10 and now I am at 13.04.

Unfortunately I now have the following problem in 13.04: I made the same edits as in 12.04 and 12.10 in order to turn off the ATI card. However now when I want to boot into 13.04 I get the following error

```
[drm:r600_uvd_init] *ERROR* UVD not responding trying to reset the VCPU!!!
```

This repeats several times

```
[drm:r600_uvd_init] *ERROR* UVD not responding giving up!!!
[drm:evergreen_startup] *ERROR* radeon: error initializing UVD (-1).
radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup CP stall for more than 10000msec
[drm:r600_lb_test] *ERROR* radeon: fence wait failed (-35).
[drm:radeon_lb_ring_tests] *ERROR* radeon: failed testing IB on GFX ring (-35).
[drm:radeon_device_init] *ERROR* lb ring test failed (-35).
```

This results in either a white screen with mouse pointer and the possibility to switch via CTRL-ALT-F1 to the terminal or on chance a switch to the actual Intel GPU followed by the login screen and a fine running Ubuntu. However as this is very inconsistent and I am afraid that the same will happen on 14.04 LTS after I upgrade I wanted to ask you guys what would be the proper way to continue at this point.